# HomeBridge eWeLink WebSocketClient: error '0' (Error: unexpected server response (200))

Tags: api, github, websocket

I hope you can help me. I will explain shortly what the situation is, I installed the app Homebridge from Github on my Raspberry: https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge

Installation was successful, so, so far so good. But then I installed the plugin eWeLink for the Homebridge app: https://github.com/gbro115/homebridge-ewelink the installation went good as well, but on the startup there seems to be a problem with the WebSocketClient, I get the following output when I start the app:

```
[2018-6-1 14:43:27] [eWeLink] A total of [0] accessories were loaded from the local cache
[2018-6-1 14:43:27] [eWeLink] Requesting a list of devices from eWeLink HTTPS API at [https://eu-ota.coolkit.cc:8080]
[2018-6-1 14:43:27] Homebridge is running on port 51826.
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] eWeLink HTTPS API reports that there are a total of [108] devices registered
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] Evaluating if devices need to be removed...
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] Evaluating if new devices need to be added...
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] Device [undefined], ID : [undefined] will be added
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] A device with an unknown type was returned. It will be skipped. undefined
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] API key retrieved from web service is [undefined]
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] Connecting to the WebSocket API at [wss://eu-api.coolkit.cc:8080/api/ws]
WebSocketClient: error { '0': Error: unexpected server response (200)
    at ClientRequest._req.on (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:653:21)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:543:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:112:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11) }
WebSocketClient: retry in 5000ms 1006
[2018-6-1 14:43:28] [eWeLink] WebSocket was closed. Reason [1006]
WebSocketClient: reconnecting...
WebSocketClient: error { '0': Error: unexpected server response (200)
    at ClientRequest._req.on (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge-ewelink/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:653:21)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:543:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:112:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11) }
WebSocketClient: retry in 5000ms 1006
[2018-6-1 14:43:34] [eWeLink] WebSocket was closed. Reason [1006]
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was just trying to set things up myself when I was looking around online to solve a different issue I had - I don’t know if this helps now but I read on the plugin’s issues page on GitHub that the eWeLink system now uses a different web socket api.

Below is my working snippet from config.json on my raspberry pi, the websocketAPI field is what you want (adjust eu to us if applicable.)

"platform" : "eWeLink",
"name" : "eWeLink",
"authenticationToken" : "8b470fda3382935147ca865c44b79dfa8055f143"
"apiHost" : "eu-api.coolkit.cc:8080",
"webSocketApi" : "eu-pconnect3.coolkit.cc"